# mysql: free space after drop table with innodb_file_per_table=False

Tags: mysql

how to reclaim free space after drop table?  the innodb_file_per_table=False;
and i'm using version:
*Server version: 5.5.44-MariaDB MariaDB Server*

Comment: asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32608884/how-to-reclaim-disk-space-in-innodb-after-dropping-table     Please give more info if that link does not provide enough info, or your situation is different.

Comment: @Luuk - That other Question is related, but not the same.

Comment: You should upgrade.

Comment: @RickJames, thanks but what to you mean should upgrade? and what to do after upgrade?

Comment: @Luuk, that questions has innodb_file_per_table=True, so it's different.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to give the free space back to the OS is to dump all the tables, remove ibdata* and reload.

Meanwhile, there is a lot of free space in ibdata1.  When you do `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, you will probably see that most tables have the same, large, `Data_free` value.  This is actually how much is free in `ibdata1`.  As you add more data (to existing or new tables), `Data_free` will decrease until it gets close to zero; then the size of the ibdata1 file will increase.

Search around for other discussions of `innodb_file_per_table`.

As for doing a backup with low disk space, consider sending the data across the network to a disk on another machine.  For example, if the MySQL server is host1, do this on host2:

```
host2> mysqldump -h host1 ... >/a/local/dumpfile.sql
```

Before you rebuild, be sure to set `innodb_file_per_table=ON` since it needs to apply when you `CREATE` the `TABLEs`.

Comment: thanks for your response. my situation is that the ibdata* file has taken up to 1.8T of almost all of the os disk space. and have only a few GBs left. so there is no available free space to dump(or backup actually?)all the tables. Do you have any pracitcal suggestions regarding my situation? and what do you mean by "there is a lot of free space in ibdata1"? do yo mean there is no need to reclaim the free space? and that mysql will use the "freed space" in ibdata1? and can we know how many free space left in ibdata1?

Comment: @DingxinXu - I heavily modify my Answer; see if it addresses your questions.

Comment: thanks i'll have a try